# t-sql string concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table that has following column

```
Type
--------
type 1
type 2
type 3
```

How can i convert the above to a string like ('type 1', 'type 2', 'type 3')

I want to use the output in my t-sql query with IN clause. Something like select * from TableA where SomeColumn IN ('Type 1','Type 2', Type 3')

I used to following to come up with output (type 1, type 2, type 3)

```
select '(' + STUFF((select ', ' + Type from TableA for xml path ('')),1,2,'') + ')'
```

But dont know how to insert the single quotes.

Comment: @CResults: *"please see my answer below"* What's the point of that comment? He'll already get a notification that you've answered, which someone with your rep clearly knows. So...?!

Comment: @stackoverflowuser - please consider editing your question to suit the accepted answer

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: Please, review my answer, you will change your mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is with a subselect:

```
select * from TableA where SomeColumn IN (
    select Type from TheOtherTable
)
```

I'm guessing you'd have a `where` clause on the subselect as well.

Depending on complexity, sometimes you do this with outer joins instead:

```
select * from TableA a
left outer join TheOtherTable b on a.SomeColumn = b.Type
where b.Type is not null
```

Which you use depends on the criteria you're applying to both the records from `TableA` and what I've called `TheOtherTable` (the one with `Type`).

Comment: i already tried that and it doesn't seem to be working. But the same approach works when dealing with integer data type

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: I've used this with `varchar` columns plenty of times; it's not a column type issue. You want to be sure that `null` doesn't appear as a result of the subselect, is your `where` on the subselect ensuring that? The more info you provide, the better, really.

Comment: you are right. i tried out on a sample table and that seems to work. But it does not work with my table. So here is the entire thing - i have a user defined function that returns a table ( ID int, TypeName varchar(8000))

i am doing this select * from TableA where Type in (select TypeName from dbo.udf_MyFunction(someinput))

But the above does not work.

Comment: my bad. i had an extra space in front of each typename that was throwing off the results.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: Cool! glad you got that solved. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Just try it for fun :)

```
declare @s1 varchar(8000)
declare @s2 varchar(8000)

update t
  set  
    @s1 = ISNULL(@s1 + ',', '') + '''' + REPLACE(t.Type, '''', '''''') + ''''
   ,@s2 = 'select * from TableA where Type IN (' + @s1 + ')' 
from TableA t

select @s2
```

`REPLACE(t.Type, '''', '''''')` - if field has any apostrophe(s) in field's text, REPLACE will double it. Try to change *type1* to *typ'e1* or *typ''e1* in your table TableA

I stopped joking...

**Try to avoid IN clause and subqueries**. They work very slow (table scan and so on...)!
Use this:

```
select a.Type 
from TableA a 
  inner join TheOtherTable b 
  on a.Type = b.Type
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need a quote, double type it

so ' becomes ''

so your code becomes

```
select '(' + STUFF((select ''',''' + Type from TableA for xml path ('')),1,2,'') + ''')'
```

The above generates

```
('type 1','type 2','type 3')
```